# manipulação de datas no postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, data

Tenho um banco de dados com vários registros, desde `2001` até `2010`. Como faço para selecionar todas as tuplas com datas depois do dia `2001-05-02`? Data é do tipo `character varying(254)`.

Comment: Para elaborar uma consulta precisamos de uma referencia ,seria por exemplo um campo data_entrada ?

Comment: queria algo do tipo: select * from historico where data > 2001-12-31. Mas não deu certo assim.

Comment: da uma olhada na minha resposta lá e bem provável que tenha sido um erro de sintaxe mesmo .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consulta usando operador `>`

**Exemplo**

```
SELECT * FROM 
MinhaTabela
WHERE data > '2001-05-02'
```

Se você deseja informar um intervalo com um determinado período. 
Você pode utilizar o operador [BETWEEN](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_between.asp)

**Exemplo** :

```
SELECT * FROM 
FROM 
MinhaTabela
WHERE 
data BETWEEN dataInicial AND dataFinal
```

Comment: o problema estava nas aspas simples mesmo. obrigada! :)